# is it possible to use "input variables" in custom order

Tags: python, regex

I'm new in python and regex.
I'm trying to make a one-line regex implementation.
In first input want to take a text to check, and for second input the regex pattern. Is it possible in python to achieve that?

```
import re
print(len(re.findall('{regex}', '{text_to_check}')).format(text_to_check=input(), regex=input()))
```

edit: to make question clearer;
due to expression console takes first input as regex into code. and second input as text for checking. I want first input to place for text for check and second one for regex.

PS: Sory for my bad english and thanks all for help.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do.  `len()` returns an integer, it doesn't have a `format()` method.

Comment: The first argument to `re.findall()` is the regular expression, the second is the string to search.

Comment: Do you mean `text_to_check = input();regex = input();re.findall(regex, text_to_check)`? Expressions in python are evaluated left to right. Maybe you wanted something like `re.findall(*[input(), input()][::-1])`?

Comment: Giacomo Alzetta thats interesting idea but how its possible to use it in one-line code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to take inputs on the same line as the function call, but reverse the order of them when calling the function? You can do that by collecting them into a list, reversing the list, and then calling the function with the splat operator.

```
print(len(re.findall(*[input("String:"), input("Regexp:")][::-1])))
```

There's no need to use `format()`, since `input()` returns a string.

Comment: Yes! thats what I'm trying to do. I couldn't make your code to work, it gives TypeError.

Comment: Fixed it. The `.reverse()` method reverses in place and returns `None`, I needed to use a slice to return the reversed list.